# Continuity Vs IVT

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Just wondering whether we can define continuity by Intermediate Value Theorem classically? I mean, are they both equivalent i.e. a function f is continues iff f satisfy IVT? Cheers!

Comment: There are functions which have intermediate value property but are discontinuous. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function).

Comment: However: You might try to prove *this* as an exercise. If $f$ takes on each value only *finitely* many times and has the IVP, then $f$ must be continuous.

Comment: see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622076/continuity-rightarrow-intermediate-value-property-why-is-the-opposite-not-tr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are nowhere -continuous functions with the IVT property, e.g.:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function