# Prove or Disprove: Summation of two functions (at least one discontinuous) supports IVP, if both of them support IVP.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, special-functions

**Let, f and g be two functions on R, support IVP and at least one them is discontinuous. Then prove or disprove ( with example) whether f+g also supports IVP.**

If f and g, both are continuous, then it is easy to say that, f+g supports intermediate-value-property. But here, we have to show, whether this result holds for discontinuous function or not.

Comment: I found a related answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624120/58577 This shows that *every* function is the sum of two functions satisfying the IVP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the interval $I=[0,1]$.

$f(x)=x$ is continuous on $I$. The map
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{for} &0 \le x <1/2\\
1 & \mbox{for} &1/2 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$

Doesn't support the IVP. However $g=h-f$ which is discontinuous does.

**Unfortunately my answer is wrong...**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But here, we have to prove whether, summation of two functions that **support ivp** (at least one discontinuous) supports ivp. Since h(x) is discontinuous but doesn't support IVP,  this example is not valid.

Comment: Please read again. $f$ is continuous. $g$ is discontinuous and supports IVP. $f+g=h$ doesn't support IVP. This answers your question (negatively).

Comment: I have tried with f as x and g as - {x}, and come up with [x] which doesn't support IVP. Since, {x} doesn't support IVP,  my example was not valid.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. Yes, it does. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am confused. Why does $g$ satisfies IVP? In fact, $g(1/4) = -1/4$, $g(3/4) = 1/4$, but $g(s) < -1/4$ for $s \in (1/4,1/2)$ and $g(s) > 1/4$ for $s \in [1/2,3/4)$. In particular, there is no $s \in (1/4,3/4)$ with $g(s) = 0$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @gerw That is good point. I'll delete the answer after its rejection.

Comment: You might want to check my (counter)example

Answer (score 0):

For any $s \in [-1,1]$, one can show that $f_s : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined via
$$f_s(x):=
\begin{cases} \sin(1/x) & \text{if } x \ne 0 \\ s & \text{else}\end{cases}$$
satisfies the IVP.

However, the difference of two such functions does clearly violate the IVP.

Comment: This indeed answers the question! I was looking to the case where one of the maps is continuous.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I have the feeling that this is not possible, but I am not sure.