# Making $|x|$ differentiable

Tags: calculus

We know that $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$ (the derivative approaches $1$ as $x \to 0^+$ while the derivative approaches $-1$ as $x \to 0^-$). However, if I were to define a function $g$ such that

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x \geq 0 \newline
-1 &\text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}$$

Then if I define $f(x) = \int_0^x g(x)$, $f(x) = |x|$ and $f'(x) = g(x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. However, in this case, $f'(0) = g(0) = 1$ but we just established in the first paragraph that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

What am I missing here?

Edit: I cannot use the fundamental theorem of calculus because $g$ is not continuous.

It turns out I cannot define an everywhere differentiable function such that its derivative is equal to $g$ by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Comment: The hypothesis on $g$ in the FTC.

Comment: The FTC is defined for continuous functions, which $g$ is not

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to define a everywhere differentiable function who's derivative is $g$?

Comment: Shouldn't this new question be a new post?

Comment: I felt it was really similar to the one I asked originally, which is why I thought to keep it to the same post. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: No, because the derivatives of a continuous functions satisfy the Intermediate Value Property (this is [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Comment: Thank you! I really learned a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function whose derivative is
$$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1&\text{if }x\geq 0,\\
-1 &\text{if }x\lt 0.
\end{array}\right.$$
This is because of [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)):

> **Darboux's Theorem.** If $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then it has the intermediate value property: for any $r$ and $s$, $a\leq r\lt s\leq b$, if $y$ is a value between $f'(r)$ and $f'(s)$, then there exists $t$, $r\lt t\lt s$, such that $f'(t)=y$.

In particular, since $g(x)$ does *not* satisfy the intermediate value property (there is no point where $g(x)$ takes values strictly between $g(-1)$ and $g(1)$, for example), it cannot be the derivative of a function.

Comment: The third answer to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622076/continuity-rightarrow-intermediate-value-property-why-is-the-opposite-not-tr?lq=1 gives an example of a function that satisfies the intermediate property but isn't continuous.

Comment: @Math_Day: Yes, such functions exist; which is why you can have a function that has a derivative, but that derivative is not continuous (among other reasons, such as explicitly constructing it). But $g(x)$ does *not* satisfy the intermediate value property, so it cannot be a derivative.

Comment: for sure, I was just including that post for those who are confused about the difference between functions that are continuous and functions that satisfy the intermediate value property

Answer (score 4):

There is even no differentiable function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x>0,\\
-1 &\text{if }x<0,
\end{cases}$$
because this would imply
$$f(x)=f(0)+|x|,$$
which is not differentiable at $0.$